# About granting permission above Marshmallow

Tags: android, android-permissions

I have read something about permissions in "https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/declaring.html".

In there i have seen "Depending on how sensitive the permission is, the system might grant the permission automatically, or the device user might have to grant the request."

For example,

**if your app requests permission to turn on the device's flashlight, the system grants that permission automatically.**

My question is that for accessing the flashlight we have **request the camera permission first.** So why is it written that for flashlight app the permission will be granted automatically?

Comment: Try this it may be work http://stackoverflow.com/a/41221852/5488468

Answer (score 2):

The [CameraManager.setTorchMode](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraManager.html#setTorchMode(java.lang.String,%20boolean)) (how you'd turn on the flashlight on API 23+ devices) does not require the `CAMERA` permission.

Comment: what about the CameraMannager?

Comment: Getting the `CameraManager` system service does not require any permissions at all (the same as system services).

Comment: can you provide a sample code of turning on and off the torch as answer.

Comment: The use of the [flashlight APIs](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0.html#flashlight) really isn't pertinent to your question about run time permissions.

Comment: i have asked about  run time permissions in Camera for using flashlight APIs.

Comment: Well if all you cared about was how to use the flashlight APIs, there are already questions for that.